# I'm trying to make this hover animation but it's not working

Tags: html, css

I used [this website](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/css-trick-animating-link-underlines/) as a source to learn how to make the hover animation.

Here is my HTML:

```css
.navLinks {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.navLinks:hover {
  color: #000;
  /* border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: .5em .5em; */
}

.navLinks:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navLinks:hover: {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <div class="menu1">
    <a href="#home" class="navLinks">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu2 ">
    <a href="#upcoming" class="navLinks">Upcoming Tournaments</a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <p>It's Academic</p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu3">
    <a href="#history" class="navLinks">History</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu4">
    <a href="#faq" class="navLinks">Contact Info</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```

I only put in the code that pertains to the animation. 
So I'm not sure why this isn't working but there's no animation when I hover.

Comment: syntax issue `navLinks:hover:before`

Answer (score 0):

Also can you change the color for the hover animation ? For instance :

```
.navLinks:hover {
   color:red;
}
```

Maybe the hover animation is working but since you don't change anything, your can't see it (by default, your text is black).

Comment: The hover animation is supposed to make an underline when hovering, not change the color so it's still visibly not working :/

Comment: sorry, I wrote too fast

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the links inside another element for it to work ! Just like in the example I provided, and you should have modified your previous question rather than posting a new one.

```css
div > a {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div > a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

div > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

div > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <div class="menu1">
    <a href="#home" class="navLinks">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu2 ">
    <a href="#upcoming" class="navLinks">Upcoming Tournaments</a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <p>It's Academic</p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu3">
    <a href="#history" class="navLinks">History</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu4">
    <a href="#faq" class="navLinks">Contact Info</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: all he need to do is add `:before` to `.navLinks:hover:`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to this website. Also, how do I change the gap between the underline and the text and also the size/boldness of the underline? Which class do I add this CSS to?

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake with targeting the (pseudo)element in your CSS. `.navLinks:hover` would target `.navLinks`. If you want to target the `.navLinks::before` when hovering on `.navLinks`, write it like this: `.navLinks:hover::before`.

You don't need to change anything about your HTML.

> **Note:** Officially, pseudo-elements are written with double :: but :
>   works too. I used double colons, but don't worry about using singles!

```css
.navLinks {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.navLinks:hover {
  color: #000;
  /*   border-left: 1px solid white;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: .5em .5em; */
}

.navLinks::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.5);
  transform: scaleX(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.navLinks:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <div class="menu1">
    <a href="#home" class="navLinks">Home</a>
  </div>

  <div class="menu2 ">
    <a href="#upcoming" class="navLinks">Upcoming Tournaments</a>
  </div>

  <div class="logo">
    <p>It's Academic</p>
  </div>

  <div class="menu3">
    <a href="#history" class="navLinks">History</a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu4">
    <a href="#faq" class="navLinks">Contact Info</a>
  </div>

</nav>
```